# Flutter. How to have constant/permanent notification running?

Tags: dart, flutter, notifications

I would love to know if it is possible to have this kind of notification using flutter. These image I made on my phone from the app "A HIIT Interval Timer". [image][image]

There is an Icon when it is resized but when you put down the notification bar it shows you the remaining time left. I would like to make a very similiar thing for my app that includes a timer. What is the correct name for this kind of notification? Where should I start looking for making this? thanks

Comment: It is a standard Android notification. [More](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Comment: that updates real time the notification? How to do it in flutter? To set up the icon and text that shows after the bar notification has been pulled down?

Comment: You need to do it natively because iOS and Android notifications are very different so I can't share any code of doing it that works in both platform (you may try some plugins).

Comment: Can you figure out this problem? I have the same issue now.

Comment: Did you make it ? Have same problem

Answer (score -1):

[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin can be used for this use case. On Android, the icon that will be used comes from the Android resources folder.

```dart
// Initialize the plugin, app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project

const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```